# linux bash: cd to directory with space

Tags: linux, bash

If having a directory name as "my dir".
I can get to the directory use this,

```
~: cd my\ dir
```

or

```
~: cd "dy dir"
```

But I found if I do this:

```
~: export my_dir=my\ dir
```

or

```
~: export my_dir="my dir"
```

then

```
~: cd $my_dir
```

it does not work, cd always get its parameter as "my " and report error.

Anyone aware how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that it is unlikely that you need to `export` that variable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The shell will split variables up on whitespace when used outside of quotation marks. Do `cd "$my_dir"` instead.

Comment: I tried the following: `export my_dir="\"my dir\""` ... notice the double-doublequotmark escaping... now `echo $my_dir` echoes `"my dir"`... but still `cd $my_dir` returns `-bash: cd: "my: No such file or directory` ... I don't get it

Answer (score 1):

Doing

```
cd "$my_dir"
```

works, but then you'll always have to remember that for my_dir you'll need to use "my_dir". An alternative solution is that you can do:

```
ln -s my\ dir my_dir
export my_dir="my_dir"
```

And now you should be able to do:

```
cd $my_dir
```

So basically create a Symbolic Link to the directory with the space and then export the symlink instead of the actual directory.

Answer (score 0):

```
alias cdmydir="cd my\ dir"
```

You won't be able to use this for any other function, like specifying paths, but it'll work for this immediate use.

I tried `export my_dir=my\\\ dir` and `export my_dir="\"my dir\""`, so that the environment variable would be `my\ dir` and `"my dir"`, respectively. But bash must do different parsing for environment variables compared to the regular command line: I got errors "No such file or directory" errors for `my\` and `"my`.

Comment: Thanks for tip! the alias can work, but i prefer using a variable. I think bdonlan's way is great.

Comment: You can also do `alias cdmydir='cd "my dir"'`.

Answer (score 0):

c () { cd "$1 $2 $3 $4"; }

In whatever bash file you think should be used. Tabbing adds the / escaping the space, so does dragging it from the GUI.

Comment: Why not `c () { cd "$@"; }`?

Comment: @Dennis: Because `"$@"` will expand to _multiple_ words; essentially a no-op in this case. `"$*"` would be closer to this answer.

Comment: @grawity: You are correct.